# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac 1{n^{1+{1/n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question is does this series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac 1{n^{1+{1/n}}}$ converge or diverge?  My immediate thought was that this looks like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$ which I know diverges.  My thinking was that my series diverges as well because for $n$ large, the series would tend to the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the harmonic series.  We get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1/n^{1+1/n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^{1/n}}=1$$
Hence the two series agree, i.e. both diverge.